# Set up a port forwarding on D-Link DSL-6850U that will work from internal network using the WAN IP

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I've got a D-Link DSL-6850U router, And I want to setup port forwarding to some server I've got at home.

The port forwarding works just fine when I'm at work, I can connect to my server by using my WAN IP. But when I'm at home, And I'm trying to connect to my WAN IP it fails.

Is there any workaround to solve that problem?

Thanks.

Comment: just connect to the server on the LAN. what you suggest is like walking out the front door, taking 1/2 a step, turning around, knocking on the door you just exited, and asking the poor maid who answers to show you to the server.

Comment: @FrankThomas But I don't want to change the configuration of my client every time I'm moving around between home and work. I want the same configuration to hold.

Comment: then you will need some extra abstraction. if you host an internal DNS server, you can add a zone that looks like your external zone (same names) but returns internal IPs.

Comment: another option is to always use a proxy when hitting your server, so that the request always comes from the outside,without hairpin.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called *a hairpin connection*, for obvious reasons. Not all routers handle that correctly.

What you can do:

1. try to see whether *hairpinning* can be allowed in your router.
2. buy a router that can do that.
3. try to use UpnP, even though not all routers allow that.
4. try to enable multicasting on your LAN
5. give this up and connect to your server via its internal IP.

I do not know any other solutions.

Comment: I was trying to lookup hairpin NAT, but can't find any technical info on it (RFC numbers, history, complications, support across devices, etc). is there some other term I should be searching for?

Comment: Wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation, suggests also the terms NAT hairpinning, NAT loopback, NAT reflection. It provides one useful reference (the other one, dead, is to **this** site!). You may try these terms.